# express-session is not setting an ID on my sessions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

I'm trying to use express-session to keep track of user sessions on [arcade.ly](https://arcade.ly). I haven't specified a value for `genid` because I'm happy (for now) to stick with the default ID generation. The problem is that no ID is being generated for my session.

Here's an example that I've captured in my server implementation by stringifying `req.session`:

```
info: Session info: {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":31535989265,"expires":"2018-07-31T21:30:05.827Z","secure":false,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/","sameSite":"lax"}}
```

As you can see, it's all good apart from the absence of the ID. I *absolutely need* an ID because I want to be able to associate certain information, such as the user starting a game, ending a game, their final score, with that session, and I want to associate it regardless of whether they logged in or not.

If they choose to log in later to record their scores then I can associate that login with their session, but forcing them to log in up-front sucks as a user-experience.

My code looks like this:

```
let cookieExpiry = new Date();
cookieExpiry.setFullYear(cookieExpiry.getFullYear() + 1);
let sessionOptions = {
    cookie: {
        path: '/',
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false,
        maxAge: null,
        expires: cookieExpiry,
        sameSite: 'lax',
    },
    name: 'arcadely.sid',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: sessionSecret.secret
};

//  In production we want to use secure cookies
if (!debugging.isDebugging()) {
    app.set('trust proxy', 1);  //  Required for secure cookie to work behind Cloudflare
    sessionOptions.cookie.secure = true;
    sessionOptions.proxy = true;
}

app.use(session(sessionOptions));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// app.use(passport.initialize());
// app.use(passport.session());

//  Dynamic content
app.get('/', homepages.serveOrRedirect);

app.get(/^\/star-castle\/?$/, (req, res) => { res.redirect(301, '/games/starcastle/'); });
app.get(/^\/games\/asteroids\/?$/, games.loadAsteroids);
app.get(/^\/games\/space-invaders\/?$/, games.loadSpaceInvaders);
app.get(/^\/games\/starcastle\/?$/, games.loadStarCastle);
```

Bearing in mind that I'm looking at this on a debug build of my site, why am I not seeing any session ID in the session object? If it's not stored in there where is it stored and how do I get it?

(The passport stuff is because ultimately I want to plug in passport login but, for now, I've commented it out just to eliminate it from enquiries, as it were. Also, `sessionSecret.secret` is just a big random string stored in another file for convenience.)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Bart

Comment: It sounds like you might be needing `uuid`. Try looking up `uuidv4` on npmjs.org. YOu could require the package in and do `sessionID = uuidv4()` and utilize as needed. I'm not certain if that is what you are needing.

Comment: Thanks - I must admit I'm tempted to try supplying a custom `genid` implementation, using `uuid` or something similar, just to check whether that's actually the problem or not. In theory it shouldn't be, according to the docs, but then the documentation can always be a bit out of date, right? One for the morning, methinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is I am a moron. Re-reading the docs at https://github.com/expressjs/session shows me that `req.session.id` is actually an alias of `req.sessionID`. If I query the latter then I get my desired session ID and we're all good.